# PHP mb_detect_encoding cannot detect encoding of CSV from Excel

Tags: php, excel, csv, encoding

When I save an Excel file as CSV and try to get the encoding via `mb_detect_encoding` like this:

```
$data = file_get_contents($csv)
$encoding = mb_detect_encoding($data);
```

It always returns false. It seems it cannot detect the encoding from the Excel generated CSV file.

I even tried saving the CSV with a different encoding in Excel, but that doesn't seem to change anything about that.

[image]
(sorry for the German UI)

What could be the reason for this and how can I fix this? I want to write a short PHP code that converts my uploaded CSV file to UTF-8 before doing any processing. But I get stuck at detecting the original encoding.

Comment: Might try this before https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-order.php

Comment: I tried that as well. It doesn't work. The problem seems to be with MS Excel. Somehow it saves the file in an unrecognizable format. When I use something else, like Google Sheets, for instance, and do an export as CSV and run that through my script, it perfectly recognizes the encoding. Just Excel doesn't seem to work, no matter what encoding I set it to.